# configure Identifier expected after this token

Tags: hibernate

I am building my first hibernate application, so i got error in configure.This is my code

```
package firsthibernate;




import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.fasterxml.classmate.AnnotationConfiguration;


public class mnapp {


    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.configure();
    serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
            configuration.getProperties()). build();
    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    return sessionFactory;









    }
}

    so, In the above code, this line (configuration.configure();) gives me error (configure Identifier expected after this token.).
```

How could i solve?

And my other code like:

This is my hibernate.cfg.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC  
          "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"  
          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">  

          <hibernate-configuration>  

    <session-factory>  
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>  
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MysqlDialect</property>  
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db</property>  
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>  
        <property name="connection.password">yellow1</property>  
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>  

    </session-factory>  

</hibernate-configuration>
```

and This is my Employee.java

```
package firsthibernate;

import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;


    @Column(name = "first_name")
     private String firstName;


    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;


    @Column(name = "salary")
    private int salary;

     public Employee() {}


     public int getId() {
          return id;
       }
       public void setId( int id ) {
          this.id = id;
       }




       public String getFirstName() {
              return firstName;
           }
           public void setFirstName( String first_name ) {
              this.firstName = first_name;
           }




           public String getLastName() {
                  return lastName;
               }
               public void setLastName( String last_name ) {
                  this.lastName = last_name;
               }


               public int getSalary() {
                      return salary;
                   }
                   public void setSalary( int salary ) {
                      this.salary = salary;
                   }
                }
```

So how could i solve this error?

Comment: This code, if representative of what you actually tried to run, is in a mess.  You never even declared the `serviceRegistry` and `sessionFactory` variables.

Comment: I removed all the code, but i am trying to setname this time, but it also gives me error: like Employee empo = new Employee();
 
 empo.setfirstName("ghh");this line gives me error, empo.setfirstName("ghh");

Comment: I have changed the code, but it gives console error, i did not find any mistake in my application this time, please take a look on my application , where should i improve my code...

Comment: Please, edit your question with changes. Which Hibernate version you use?

Comment: hibernate-release-5.1.0.final

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: firsthibernate.employee
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:776)
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1542)
 at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:225)

Comment: these are some lines of my console